# Preventing Electron to exit fullscreen on Escape

Tags: electron

ever since Electron 18.0.1 introduced [this PR](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/32369) I am having trouble with pressing Escape in fullscreen. Trouble is that my Electron application is running in fullscreen and I want  my app to handle Esc key. However ever since electron 18.0.1, when I press Esc, I am kicked out of fullscreen - I guess it's because Esc key is some "magical system key" that is handled by Electron itself.

Could you please help me, how to prevent Electron from exiting fullscreen when Esc is pressed?

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Electron 18.0.1 or 18.0.2. What OS are you on?

Comment: Linux Mint, but it happens in Arch, too

Comment: Can't reproduce in on Kubuntu 21.10. F11 goes fullscreen but ESC does not exit it for me. Are you able to create this issue in an [Electron Fiddle](https://www.electronjs.org/fiddle)?

Comment: It happens when the application was fullscreened by a video stream.

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.keyboard` can realize long presses of the Escape button to exit full screen, so you can intercept the Escape key event like this:

```js
if (navigator.keyboard && navigator.keyboard.lock){
  navigator.keyboard.lock(['Escape'])
} else {
  console.log("Your app doesn't support navigator.keyboard")
}
```